# Not able to run ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseNameHere] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE On Azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-server

I have created SQL Database on **Azure SQL server service**, and trying to enabled Service Broker, but getting below Error.

Error :*The operation cannot be performed on database "DatabaseNameHere" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.*

Comment: Follow the steps here: http://www.sqlnuggets.com/blog/change-the-isolation-level-of-an-availability-group-database/

Comment: Thanks Eray! please let me know, How to get AVAILABILITY GROUP